# HecaDecimal X value when converting to hex?

Tags: c#, .net

So I was in a middle of converting string to hex value represenation and By mistake instead of writing
`ToString("X0")`

I wrote

`ToString("X100")`

```
var t="123";
for (int i=0;i<t.Length;i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine( ((int)t[i]).ToString("X100"));
}
```

the values were :

```
X149
X150
X151
```

p.s. :

`ToString("X10")` yields :

```
0000000031
0000000032
0000000033
```

`ToString("X99")` yields : ( same with many zeros)

but when jumping like 100 , 1000 , 10000.... it yields somwthing with `X`

what is this X representation ? `X149` for example...?

Comment: offhand, looks like "X1" + decimal value, not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `x` and `X` format specifiers, as with all of the [standard numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), you can only request up to 99 digits. Once you try to ask for more than that, you no longer have a standard format specifier, but a custom one.

In a custom format specifier, '0' means to include a digit in the original number, and everything else is kept as a constant.

So:

```
19.ToString("X8") = "00000013"
19.ToString("X99") = "0000...0013" // 99 digits
19.ToString("X100") = "X119"; // "X1" + 19.ToString("00")
19.ToString("X101") = "X1191" // "X1" + 19.ToString("0") + "1"
29.ToString("X1010") = "X1219" // "X1" + 2.ToString("0") + "1" + 9.ToString("0")
```

etc.

(To explain that last one: each 0 represents the *next digit* in the number being formatted; the first 0 was replaced by a 2, the second 0 was replaced by a 9. These get really tricky really fast.)

Comment: Good answer. It goes for all the [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) that the precision specifier can have only one or two digits (that is from `0` through `9`, or `00` through `99`). For an `int` (that is `Int32`), only eight hex digits are needed to hold any number. Note that if you use a precision specifyer greater than `8`, negative numbers will look "funny" with `0`s instead of `F`s being prepended. Example: `(-1).ToString("X12")`. Also, using a lesser precision specifyer: `(-1).ToString("X6")` will show eight `F`s anyway.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen you're right; I didn't mean to imply that X/x were "special" here, I'll update my answer.